# Sharing Apache Server with the Internet?

Tags: apache

I installed Apache with WAMP. I want to make my computer as a server for my web page for make some experiment on my web site.But I can`t open my server in Internet. I can see it in http://localhost/mysite/index.html but when I try to reach it in another computer like http://myserverip/mysite/index.html  it says server not responding. I am using wireless router and also forwarded to my LAN ip.

Answer (score 0):

A few ideas:

- check that apache is bound to your PC's internal IP rather than just localhost - run `netstat -an` and verify that you have local address 0.0.0.0:80 not 127.0.0.1:80
- check that you're definitely forwarding port 80 from the router to your PC
- check that you're not firewalling off the traffic, i.e. make sure there's an exception in the windows firewall for port 80 (and 443 if you're using HTTPS), or a program exception for httpd, or even try turning off the firewall temporarily whilst debugging this
- find out if your ISP is blocking this - some won't let you run web servers from your home connection; you could try a different web port to see if that helps?
- try connecting from some other machine - there could be some proxy configuration that's upsetting looping back into your PC

Comment: I have nod32. I closed internet filter and now it says that you have no permissionto access on this server .403 Forbidden. Is it about windows firewall?

Comment: I don't know nod32, sorry, but Windows firewall wouldn't generate that: instead it would just refuse the connection. A 403 error is probably being generated by Apache - maybe check the Apache logs to see?